# Reddit json and PHP - opening foreach() and getting values

Tags: php, json, reddit

I am trying to read a reddit json using my account as an example.

Tried the solution above as:

```
$string_reddit = file_get_contents("https://www.reddit.com/user/joshfolgado/about.json");

$json = json_decode($string_reddit, true);  

$children = $json['data'];
foreach ($children as $child){

$linkkarma = $child['data']['link_karma'];

}
```

Also tried:

```
foreach ($json->data as $mydata){

$values["Latest_Karma"] = $mydata['link_karma'];

}
```

Also tried:

```
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"User-Agent: reddiant api script\r\n"
));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://www.reddit.com/user/joshfolgado/about.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$result = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($result as $child){
    $values['Latest_Karma'] = $child['data']['link_karma'];
}
```

Spent a couple of hours trying do get the values for any of the items inside the "data" array, havent been able to get any.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Whats the error that youre getting? Is it displaying an error or just not returning anything when you run the foreach?

Comment: Dump the response and see what it actually contains?

Comment: It doesnt any error, what happens is that  $values['Latest_Karma'] doesnt return a value

Comment: Need to restart my machine, back in a few minutes

Comment: @JoshFolgado Check my answer it works for me, and i think that `$values['Latest_Karma']` Doesn't exist in the JSON response, did you mean link karma?

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r` the decoded object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification to pee2pee's post (His returned an undefined index error for me)

```
$string_reddit = file_get_contents("http://www.reddit.com/user/joshfolgado/about.json");
$json = json_decode($string_reddit, true);

$children = $json['data'];
$user = [];

foreach ($children as $key => $value)
{
    $user[$key] = $value;
}

echo $user['name']; //Now you can use the $user array to access all the properties!
```

This works for me ->

[image]

Comment: Great input Kenziiee.

A question.

How do I get the value for example for "comment_karma"?

Basically I need to get various values and assign them to variables within my system.

Comment: Within the foreach loop it echos the key which would be comment karma and the value which in your case would be 47, you would use the loop to assign them dynamically. Or would you like to see the code?

Comment: Thanks a lot Kenziiee! If you can show me the code would be great!

Comment: @JoshFolgado Unfortunately my working day is over now, if you still need help tomorrow id be happy to help but for now a little research + my code should get you sorted!

Comment: I will keep on trying until later and if I find out do it I will update you here.

If you could send me tomorrow the answer with the code would really help, having lots of pressure to have it done.

Have a good evening and again thanks

Comment: Good morning @Kenziiee, hope your day started well.

I didnt come right last night, any chance of helping me with the issue today?

Many thanks

Comment: @JoshFolgado Morning and thanks, was just wondering in what way are you doing to be using the data? Like just to set variables or to do more things with can you give me an example it would help the code

Comment: Good morning Keeziiee.

I am using a tool called PHPRunner.

What I am doing is that when the that foreach loop runs I need the following variables such as:

$values['Latest_Karma'] = 'link_karma'
$values["Comment_Karma"] = 'comment_karma'
$values["RedditID"] = 'id'

Once those variables have values I can use them and will also assign them to session variables where applicable, such as the redditID for the user. 

Thanks a lot for taking the time to help, would be great to chat via skype or email.

Comment: @JoshFolgado There you go updated the code, you can use the `$user` array variable to get all the data back for that current user, if you want to see whats available to you do `die(var_dump($user))` and it will show you the array values that are available

Comment: With @Keeziiee's help got the code doing what was needed. Below a copy of the final solution.

    $result = json_decode($json, true);
    $children = $result['data'];
    $user = [];

    foreach ($children as $key => $value)
      {

       $user[$key] = $value;
       $values['Link_Karma'] = $user['link_karma'];

      }

Thanks a lot Keeziiee, appreciate your help, have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string_reddit = file_get_contents("http://www.reddit.com/user/joshfolgado/about.json");
$json = json_decode($string_reddit, true);  

$children = $json['data'];
foreach ($children as $child){
    $link_karma= $child['link_karma'];
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it didnt work, its an efficient answer.